# Setting Pakyow for local development with Postgres

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, pakyow

In the blog post about connection to postgres, http://notmagic.org/2015/04/10/pakyow-sequel, how do you deal with Postgres setup and required password errors?

I've been developing in Nitrous.io but now setting up local development. So I set the `DATABASE_URL` as in the post but trying to run `pakyow server` it gives an error about: "pg::connectionbad: fe_sendauth: no password"

The only user in Postgres is 'postgres' and it has a password associated. It wouldn't let me install without creating a password.

Also, is it bad practice to not have a Postgres password for local dev? Articles about it weren't clear (and were related to Rails) and mentioned database.yml storing the password, which Pakyow doesn't seem to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the post, you'll want to include the password in the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable (in your local `.env` file). The url should be structured like: `postgres://user:password@host/database`.

It's best to always have a password for your Postgres user, be it locally or in production. You want to make it as difficult as possible for someone to see your data :-)